# Anaconda fails to install fully on WIndows 7 [Solved: Bad Hard Drive]

Tags: anaconda

[edit] The issue here turned out to be a problem with my hard drive.

I'm trying to install Anaconda3 on Windows 7. I have no other Python installations. I have tried several dozen times, scrubbing and rebooting between each run. I have tried several versions of the Anaconda3 installer. I have tried every combination of admin/not admin and PATH/register. No matter what I try, I get the same result: the installation completes and the packages are extracted, but I have no menu shortcuts and can't run anything. Show Details has a bunch of errors referring to missing modules and an inability to run conda.exe. I was able to install without a problem on a different box running Windows 10.

Partial output pasted below beginning with the first error which appears after the stack of Extract messages.

```
*** BEGIN PARTIAL OUTPUT ***
Extract: anaconda-2019.07-py37_0.tar.bz2
[5504] Failed to execute script conda.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 149, in __init__
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conda.exe.py", line 45, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\libarchive\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\libarchive\entry.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\libarchive\ffi.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 151, in __init__
__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Users\\Hammer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI47362\\archive.dll'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 149, in __init__
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1043, in __call__
  File "site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
  File "site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 80, in do_call
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\libarchive\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\libarchive\entry.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\libarchive\ffi.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 151, in __init__
__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Users\\Hammer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI16922\\archive.dll'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 149, in __init__
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conda.exe.py", line 88, in <module>
  File "site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 150, in main
  File "site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1335, in conda_exception_handler
  File "site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1046, in __call__
  File "site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1090, in handle_exception
  File "site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1101, in handle_unexpected_exception
  File "site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1171, in print_unexpected_error_report
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\conda_package_handling\tarball.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\libarchive\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\libarchive\entry.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Wani\mc36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
[5296] Failed to execute script conda.exe
  File "site-packages\libarchive\ffi.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 151, in __init__
__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Users\\Hammer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI16922\\archive.dll'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
Delete file: C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda3\pkgs\env.txt
Output folder: C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda3\conda-meta
Extract: history
Creating Anaconda3 menus...
Execute: "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py" mkdirs
Running post install...
Execute: "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py" post_install
Execute: "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda3\pkgs\.cio-config.py" "C:\Users\Hammer\Downloads\Anaconda3-2019.07-Windows-x86_64.exe"
Created uninstaller: C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda3\Uninstall-Anaconda3.exe
Completed
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I apologize my question disguised as an answer. Wrong button.
My solution is:

1. Uninstall every Anaconda version
2. Check `c:\users\user_name\appdata` for the directory conda and delete it
3. Check `c:\users\user_name\` for directory `.conda` and delete it
4. install `Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64.exe 661.7M 2019-04-04 16:00:30 bfb4da8555ef5b1baa064ef3f0c7b582`
5. Execute `conda update conda`
6. Execute `conda update anaconda`
7. Execute `conda update --all`
8. Execute `conda list anaconda$`

Number 8 shows the actual Version.
I hope this helps someone else.